# Perform PHP function on radio button click, Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have two radio buttons in a wordpress file. I have two contact-form-7 shortcodes and want to execute one if the radio is clicked "Yes" and the other if the radio button is "No". I am willing to use ajax as i don't want the page to reload but have no idea how to use it. It will be great if you could guide me.

Example HTML:

```
<input type=radio name=radio value=yes/>
<input type=radio name=radio value=no/>

<script>
if(radio==yes){
call_php_shortcode1();
}elseid(radio == no){
call_php_shortcode2();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can use ajax

Answer (score 1):

**Please go through the following steps.**

**Step-1:** Copy and Paste the below radion buttons code in your php file.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" onclick="getRadioVaal(this.value)"/>Form1

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no" onclick="getRadioVaal(this.value)"/> Form2  

<div id="result"></div>
```

**Step-2:** Copy and Paste the below javascript code in same php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function getRadioVaal(radio_val){
           // alert(radio_val);
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            data: "action=get_radio_button_vale&radio_val="+radio_val,
            success:function(response){
                                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });

        }
        </script>
```

**Step-2:** Copy and Paste the below code snipeet in your theme **functions.php** file.

```
//Ajax call for display form on click radio button
function display_contact_form(){
     if($_POST['radio_val'] === 'yes'){
            echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="28" title="Contact form 1"]');
        }else if($_POST['radio_val'] === 'no'){
            echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="29" title="Contact form 2"]');
        }
       exit;

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_radio_button_vale', 'display_contact_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_radio_button_vale', 'display_contact_form' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function on click radio button first:

```
$('#radioButtonContainerId input:radio').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
      myFunction();
    } else if ($(this).val() === '2') {
      myOtherFunction();
    } 
  });
```

Then inside the function you can call ajax,

```
function myFunction(){
$.ajax(this.href, {
      success: function(data) {
         $('#main').html($(data).find('#main *'));
         $('#notification-bar').text('The page has been successfully loaded');
      },
      error: function() {
         $('#notification-bar').text('An error occurred');
      }
   });
}
```

You can direct call the ajax also inside the radio button is checked condition.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.